# executing javascript code inside Android "java" application

Tags: java, javascript, android, javascript-engine

I'm working on an Android app "native written in java"
and I'm getting a response from a server the response is a javascript function

I need to use this function to do some calculations inside my native java code.

any ideas how to do so.

**sample response :**

```
function logic_1(surveyString, responseValuesString) { 
    var survey = eval(surveyString);
    var responseValues = eval(responseValuesString);
    var target = new Object();
if (isChosen(128133225, responseValues)) { 
target.id = 2;
}
if (! target.id) { 
    target.id = 2;
 } 
    return target;
 }
```

Comment: Maybe the response could be the result of the function, or a code indicating a java function to run?

Comment: what response are you getting

Comment: the response is a javascript function

Comment: i want to use this JS code inside my java code

Comment: Really suggest to change how the server is responding in case you had access to that. It's a bad habit to return programming-specific data to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've previously used Rhino successfully to execute JavaScript code on Android:
http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/

Comment: I'm getting response as a function that takes 2 input parameters .. can I give this function input from my java code ?

I mean "function logic_1(surveyString, responseValuesString)"

any way to set those 2 parameters from Java ??

Comment: Yes, this is not a problem with the Rhino APIs. This answer describes how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3996115/511012

Comment: works perfect ! thanks
okay just another question ... you can see that the function is returning an object 


    var target = new Object();

I was able to catch an integer, boolean, string in the return

but how to catch an object ?

Comment: I've posted an example as a separate answer, so I could include code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to return values from a complex type:

```
String strFunction = 
        "function add(x,y){ " +
            "return { " +
                "id:x+y " +
            "}; " +
        "}";

Context context = Context.enter();
ScriptableObject scope = context.initStandardObjects();
context.evaluateString(scope, strFunction, "test", 1, null);

Function functionAdd = (Function)scope.get("add");
NativeObject untypedResult = (NativeObject)functionAdd.call(context, scope, scope, new Object[] { 1, 2 });
double id = (Double)untypedResult.get("id", untypedResult);
```

The important part is the last two lines, where we call the JavaScript function, treat the result as a NativeObject, and then retrieve the value of the 'id' property from that object.

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava what don't you understand?

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava Not specifically, it's for Java using the Mozilla Rhino library: http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/. It will work on Android though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to use a `JavaScript auto executing function` like this:

```
(function(x, y){
  var result;
  result = x + y; // do some calculations
  return result;
})(1 , 2); //  you can set your parameters from Java
```

and `1, 2` are just two parameters from Java