# How to pass an instance of a java object to be used in Rhinoscript?

Tags: javascript, java, android, rhino

So, I want to pass a `TextView` to a Rhino function in Android.

Learned how to call js functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995897/rhino-how-to-call-js-function-from-java)

The relevant Java:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
Object result = fct.call(context, scope, scope, new Object[]{tv});
```

The relevant Javascript:

```
function doSomething(tv)
{
    tv.setText("Hello");
}
```

I get an error when calling `TextView` methods.

In response to @NathanTuggy NoSuchMethod exception... I know for a fact that android TextView has a method `setText(String s)` method as I have used it many times. I literally copied and pasted the javascript code from my file... From my experience in javascript it should be 100% correctly formatted.

Comment: What error do you get?